# Why doesn't the knight cover all the table?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I want the knight to start at `(1,1)` and to try to move all over the table. This is my code:

```
canMove :: (Int  -> Int) -> (Int  -> Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> Bool

canMove (x) (y) list 
        | (x (fst lastMove),y (snd lastMove)) `elem` list = False
        | newX> 8 || newY> 8 || newX<=0 || newY<=0 = False
        | otherwise = True
        where lastMove = last list
              newX = x (fst lastMove)
              newY = y (snd lastMove)

move :: [(Int, Int)] -> [( Int, Int)]
move list 
  | length list == 64 = list
  | canMove (+1) (+2) list = move (list ++ [(x+1,y+2)])
  | canMove (+2) (+1) list = move (list ++ [(x+2,y+1)])
  | canMove (subtract 1) (+2) list = move (list ++ [(x-1,y+2)])
  | canMove (subtract 2) (+1) list = move (list ++ [(x-2,y+1)])
  | canMove (subtract 1) (subtract 2) list = move (list ++ [(x-1,y-2)])
  | canMove (subtract 2) (subtract  1) list = move (list ++ [(x-2,y-1)])
  | canMove (+1) (subtract 2) list = move (list ++ [(x+1,y-2)])
  | canMove (+2) (subtract 1) list = move (list ++ [(x+2,y-1)])
  | otherwise = list
   where lastMove = last list
         x = fst lastMove
         y = snd lastMove

y=length (move [(1,1)])

main = print $ y
```

Why does the knight stop after `34` steps?

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you're attempting to solve the [knight's tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) problem in Haskell. In that case, your problem is that you're using the greedy algorithm, which fails for the knight's tour problem. If you remove the `length` from your `y` function, you can see the path your algorithm chose.

```
[(1,1),(2,3),(3,5),(4,7),(6,8),(5,6),(7,7),(5,8),(4,6),(6,7),
 (8,8),(7,6),(5,7),(7,8),(6,6),(8,7),(7,5),(6,3),(8,4),(6,5),
 (8,6),(7,4),(5,5),(3,6),(4,8),(2,7),(1,5),(3,4),(2,6),(3,8),
 (1,7),(2,5),(3,7),(1,8)]
-- From (1,8), we can go to either (4,6) or (3,5).
-- But we've already been to both of those positions.
```

Simply put, your knight made a "wrong" turn at some point and got itself stuck in a position where it couldn't get out without repeating a position. To circumvent this, you'll need to use some kind of backtracking algorithm, so that when the knight makes a mistake like this, it can undo its moves and try something else. Fortunately for you, Haskell makes this relatively easy with the List monad. If you're not familiar with monads, they're integral to Haskell, and you can learn about them [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads).